# Laravel 5.1 Mail::send .env configuration doesn't work

Tags: php, email, laravel, config, laravel-5.1

I have a queued job that is supposed to send emails. I keep getting an error:

> Swift_TransportException(code: 530): Expected response code 250 but
>   got code \"530\", with message \"530 5.7.1 Authentication
>   required\r\n\" at
>   /my/project/path/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383

I tried using `mail`, `sendmail` and `smtp` drivers. However if I set config values directly via `mail.php` in `config` dir it seems to work fine.

Once I get back to `.env` configuration it's the same problem again.

I tried outputting `.env` and `config` values in my templates - they all seem fine.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you show us the `mail.php` and the part of `.env` for sending mails? Make sure you remove your passwords first.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that .env configuration is not loaded in queued jobs. It is loaded in direct controllers though. What can be causing this? I'm checking file permissions, queue user etc. now. The config values are fine, I'm sure about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was in queue:listener.

Spend a lot of time trying to figure out why my config is being replaced with a wrong one.

Finally killing the `php artisan queue:listen` process and letting supervisor restart it solved everything.

Still not sure what was causing that. Maybe the .env was cached or something. Restarting the process did the trick.

Comment: any other suggestions? Did not work for me.. story of my life

Comment: No. I'm sorry. Didn't have the issue ever since. You might wanna make sure you clear your config cache, restart your queues and workers and debug what data is actually used when emailing

Answer (score 0):

It occurs just because your changes are not detected by artisan so it requires restarting artisan. There is nothing to do with `php artisan queue:listen`